# How do I zone pod lights on a single circuit without adding more wiring from the light switch (I can only branch off two ceiling spots)?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have this layout, this is a big entertainment room in the basement
Unfortunately there is a single circuit and a light switch on that circuit
Is there any solution to create lighting zones (at least two) and to switch them on selectively?

As of now the ceiling is finished and I only have control to two electrical boxes on the ceiling which are the locations of the two lights that were there before

the layout was determined based on this calculator
https://blog.recessedlighting.com/recessed-lighting-calculator/

Seems to be a little off since the rule of the thumb is to space the lights at a distance that is half of the height of the room (7" in my case)

[image]

Comment: Each zone will need it's own switch.  Do not know if there is any like automotive type light switch with different zones for 120 volt circuits.

Comment: I think I will have to use Alexa and a Sonoff switch concealed behind the ceiling next to the podlight at the demarcation point between zones

Comment: Or smart bulbs…

Comment: it would be too expensive

Comment: You should have pre-planned for this. Since you cannot pull in more wire from the switch compromise and use a dimmer. At 7" (7 inches) I do not see how you could even get into the room I believe you meant 7' (7 feet).

Comment: What's the "8"  and "158"?  Some units would help.

Comment: At 8 by 158 that is a long thin room in any units…

Comment: Edited the question and updated the picture. It is 7' tall and the size (WxL) are in Inches